# How to defeat "Blog pages show at most __ posts" setting in the loop?

Tags: theme-development, loop

I'm using this script on my archive.php in order to list a link list of all posts contained in the current category. However, its limiting the result count relative to the number assigned to "Settings > Reading > Blog Pages Show At Most *_* posts".

In other words, there may be 10 posts that are in this category, but its only displaying up to the number assigned in that setting.

How can I change my script to ignore this setting?

```
<?php if(is_category()) while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a> 
        <?php echo get_link_excerpt(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; } ?>
```

Comment: To the person who voted this down, I'm sure you had a valid reason in the spirit of improving the question, but please at least take the time to comment on how the question could be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the default loop, perhaps try [building](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) your own [query.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

Basically, it'll look something like this:

```
$your_posts = get_posts('cat=123&posts_per_page=123');
foreach ($your_post as $post) {
   do_something-with($post);
}
```

You can display all posts by either use the param `'posts_per_page'=>-1` or `nopaging=true`.

(Not sure why someone voted this down? IMHO said person should comment on how the question should be improved if she or he is going to do that.)

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

To modify the `posts_per_page` setting on a contextual basis, the best approach is to filter the query via callback to `pre_get_posts`. For example, to set `posts_per_page` to **10** for a specific category (say, category ID **7**):

```
function wpse8982_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_category( 7 ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse8982_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Note that you can pass [any valid setting for `posts_per_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something other than the automagical defaults allow for, you need to take control of your Loop. Read the docs on [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and take particular notice of the section labeled Multiple Loops. It shows alternate ways of setting up the query and displaying things. You should also take a look at [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) as that is key to what is going on here.